# Z-index Problems and Buttons CSS

Tags: css, button, header, scrollbar, z-index

I'm building a website with a fixed `header`. The `z-index` is set to a positive 1. However, it covers the scrollbar on the side.

Here is a small-scale example of my problem:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

main {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>This is the header.</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <button>Button</button>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <button>Button</button>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
</main>
```

When I set the `z-index` of the `header` to negative 1, and set the `z-index` of the `main` to a -2 so that the header is on top of the main, the buttons within the `main` are now unclickable. I've already set the position of `main` relative as well.

Is there any way to fix the `header` not covering the scrollbar, while also not affecting the `button` of the `main`.

Comment: Just updated it. Thanks!

Comment: A negative `z-index` means `<main>` (and `<header>`, for that matter) is lower than its parent `<body>`.

Comment: Yeah, so as you can see from the code I set the `z-index` of the `header` to a positive 1. But now the problem is it's covering the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after a top-fixed header that does not cover any content, including scrollbars, consider using `position: sticky`. This method means there are no "magic numbers", as is the case with the `top: 60px`, and makes the layout more resilient to future change:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flow-root;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flow-root;
  background-color: yellow;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>This is the header.</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <button>Button</button>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <button>Button</button>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
</main>
```

If you do not want the scrollbar to be on the right of the header, you could use a vertical flex layout, and have the content wrapper grow/shrink to the available space and have the content wrapper scroll instead of the `<body>`:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

main {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>This is the header.</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <button>Button</button>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <button>Button</button>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
</main>
```

Otherwise, if you really only want the scrollbar to be visible, then you would need to subtract the width of the scrollbar from the `width: 100%` value in the `header` rule. However, you would need to have some sort of operating-system detection and possibly other software detection. This is because at least on Chrome on Windows 11 that I am on, the scrollbar is `17px` wide, but if I remember correctly, macOS have overlay scrollbars (by default), as a single example. See the following that works for Chrome on Windows 11 as of the time of writing, but you may see a gap with other software configurations:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 17px);
  z-index: 1;
}

main {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>This is the header.</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <button>Button</button>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <button>Button</button>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
  <h2>Just some text.</h2>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I opted for the first option you provided. Super thanks!